# BasicDBObjectBuilder not appending mutiple criteria for a single object

Tags: java, regex, mongodb, mongodb-java, nosql

I am using Java driver for mongo-db and trying to add multiple query criteria using BasicDBObjectBuilder. I have a text field where an XML is stored as String so we are using regex to form the query.

Below is my query and the output I am getting:

```
regexQuery.put("REQUEST_XML",BasicDBObjectBuilder
.start("$regex", ".*Main>[\r\n]<.?.?.?.?action>"+MainValue+".*")
.add("$regex", ".*Details>[\r\n]<.?.?.?.?action>" + DetailValue+ ".*").get());
regexQuery.put("NAME", "Video");
```

What I am getting as query is :

```
{ "REQUEST_XML" : { "$regex" : ".*Details>[\r\n]<.?.?.?.?action>Change.*"} , "NAME" : "Video"}
```

The first part with .start("$regex", ".*Main>[\r\n]<.?.?.?.?action>"+MainValue+".*") is not getting added to query.

Can you please let me know what is the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the key value pair. `"$regex", ".*Details>[\r\n]<.?.?.?.?action>" + DetailValue+ ".*"` overwrites `"$regex", ".*Main>[\r\n]<.?.?.?.?action>"+MainValue+".*"`.

Use `$or` to pass both regex expression.

Something like

```
BasicDBObject regexQuery = new BasicDBObject();
regexQuery.put("$or", Arrays.asList(new BasicDBObject("REQUEST_XML", new BasicDBObject("$regex", ".*Main>[\r\n]<.?.?.?.?action>"+".*")),
                new BasicDBObject("REQUEST_XML", new BasicDBObject("$regex", ".*Details>[\r\n]<.?.?.?.?action>"+".*"))));
regexQuery.put("NAME", "Video");
```

This should output query like

```
{ "$or" : [{ "REQUEST_XML" : { "$regex" : ".*Main>[\r\n]<.?.?.?.?action>.*" } }, { "REQUEST_XML" : { "$regex" : ".*Details>[\r\n]<.?.?.?.?action>.*" } }], "NAME" : "Video" }
```

Using 3.x driver

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.or;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.regex;
Bson regexQuery = or(regex("REQUEST_XML", ".*Main>[\r\n]<.?.?.?.?action>"+".*"), regex("$regex", ".*Details>[\r\n]<.?.?.?.?action>"+".*"));
```

Comment: You have saved me this time :) I have used $and operator and it works like a charm. But due to more than 20 lakh records the query runs for more than 3 minutes. is there a way to optimize the query run time to less than a minute please ?